# Copying of mysql binary log files

Tags: mysql, backup

If I copy mysql binary log files (`/var/lib/mysql/mydb` the `.frm` and `.ibd` files) from one mysql instance to another, will the databases be copied over correctly (assuming using the same mysql server version)?

Comment: This question appears off-topic and better suited for [dba.se]

Comment: If MySQL is stopped - then it's OK. If not - it's a reliable way to corrupt your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a utility to do this, something like MySQLDump. You way of copying the files will require manually correcting the conf files and possibly missing something.

look Here for [Mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)